# boolean algebra simplification provided equation

Tags: boolean, algebra, boolean-algebra

i  have this one

OM5= NOT ( A OR (B AND C)) OR D

i provided i photo of it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/opS1I.png

I used different calcs that were online and all gave me this result
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+(a+or+b%26%26c)+or+d like the wolframalpha one!

But when i did it with my hand i had different results.

the result was  NOT(A) AND ( NOT(B) OR NOT(C) OR D )

Comment: De Morgans law springs to mind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  NOT ( A OR (B AND C)) OR D
= (NOT A AND NOT (B AND C)) OR D
= (NOT A AND (NOT B OR  NOT C)) OR D
= (NOT A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND NOT C) OR D
```

That's it.

Comment: the last one is the simplified answer;